# REGEX - Need a way of negative lookbehind'ing multiple strings

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match unwanted regions in filenames to delete the files.

I want to get any match if the REGEX finds a "bad region" `(Brazil or Columbia)` BUT not if they are mixed in with "good regions" in the same bracket `(USA, UK, Europe, Australia)`.

I have a regex of

`(?<![( ](USA)[,)])[( ](Brazil|Columbia)[,)](?![( ](USA|UK|Europe|Australia)[,)])`

```
FIFA Soccer (USA, Brazil)      <<< DON't MATCH IF USA IS IN SAME BRACKET BEFORE
FIFA Soccer (Brazil, USA)      <<< DON't MATCH IF USA IS IN SAME BRACKET AFTER
FIFA Soccer (Brazil)           <<< MATCH
FIFA Soccer (Brazil, Ireland)  <<< MATCH
FIFA Soccer (Moon, Brazil)     <<< MATCH
```

So far the correct lines match, but that's because I have a fixed-width "negative lookbehind" looking for "USA"...... but I also want "UK" "Europe" and "Australia" in my negative lookbehinds, and I can't do that as they have to be "fixed width"...

```
FIFA Soccer (UK, Brazil) <<< ERROR - THIS ONE SHOULDN'T MATCH AND DOES
FIFA Soccer (Brazil, UK) <<< This one works (no match) because I have my lookahead set up
```

See the live demo:
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/hkl28F/1)

So is there a way of getting in effect somehing like `(?<![( ](USA|UK|Europe|Australia)[,)])` at the start of the REGEX to unmatch things like `UK, Brazil` and `Europe, Brazil`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
\((?!(?:[^()]*,\s*)?(?:USA|UK|Europe|Australia)\s*[,)])[^()]*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FyStPk/2)

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?!(?:[^()]*,\s*)?(?:USA|UK|Europe|Australia)\s*[,)])` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match if, immediately to the right, there is

  - `(?:[^()]*,\s*)?` - an optional sequence of

    - `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
    - `,` - a comma
    - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:USA|UK|Europe|Australia)` - one of the good values
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `[,)]` - a `,` or `)`
- `[^()]*` - 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of variable length negative lookbehind, you may use PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` in alternation to match and reject a match:

```
(?:USA|UK|Europe|Australia),\h*(?:Brazil|Austria)[,)](*SKIP)(*F)|(?:Brazil|Austria)[,)](?!\h?(?:USA|UK|Europe|Australia)[,)])
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hkl28F/2)

- `(*FAIL)` behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehind in above regex.

---

You may use `DEFINE` verb in PCRE to avoid repetitions in your regex like this:

```
/
(?(DEFINE) # use define to avoid repetitions
  (?<ct>USA|UK|Europe|Australia) # disallow countries
  (?<mct>Brazil|Austria) # matching countries
)
# main regex starts here
(?&ct),\h*(?&mct)[,)](*SKIP)(*F)
|
(?&mct)[,)](?!\h?(?&ct)[,)])
/x
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hkl28F/4)

Answer (score 0):

Using a pattern to extract country names and `array_filter`:

```
$filenames = ['FIFA Soccer (USA, Brazil)',
              'FIFA Soccer (Brazil, USA)',
              'FIFA Soccer (Brazil)',
              'FIFA Soccer (Brazil, Ireland)',
              'FIFA Soccer (Moon, Brazil)'];

$bad = ['Brazil', 'Columbia'];
$good = ['USA', 'UK', 'Europe', 'Australia'];

$todelete = array_filter($filenames, function ($i) use ($bad, $good) {
    $countries = preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A), |\()\K\pL+~', $i, $m) ? $m[0] : [];
    return array_intersect($countries, $bad) && !array_intersect($countries, $good);
});

print_r($todelete);
```